# How can I cancel a Deutsche Bahn ticket? I am covid positive

Tags: trains, covid-19, deutsche-bahn

I just got corona positive, and we are going to travel from [Berlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin) to [Munich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munich) on [ICE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercity_Express). The ticket is booked via https://bahn.com in the next two days.

When I am trying to cancel the ticket, I see this:

[image: ICE Screenshot]

It looks like the cancellation is not possible anymore. Is there anything I can do in this matter?

Comment: What type of ticket (fare) was it? Not familiar with DB's fares, but I'm pretty sure some fares are flexible and others not. Also, do you have travel insurance covering this trip?

Comment: Unfortunately, this one is from non-flexi.

Comment: If your ticket is non refundable that's it. Contact your travel insurance.

Comment: In some (most?) jurisdictions travelling while covid positive is absolutely legal. Just leaving this comment here for future askers.

Comment: Covid is the main reason I am buying only Sparpreis tickets for the last 2.5 years - because Super Sparpreis is not refundable.

Comment: I guess, as all others here, you mean refunding rather than cancellation. I guess the train company does not worry about one passenger fewer on that train (which is what a cancellation without a refund would tell them.)

Comment: What do you mean by "next two days"? Valid for the next two days? Bought two days ago? Something else?

Comment: It's no longer relevant if you're covid positive.

Comment: @DanubianSailor: Huh? It's of course Ländersache (up to the state), but e.g. here in Hesse, it's stay in isolation for 5 full days after the day of your first positive test. Berlin has 10 days, but after 5 (and no symptoms since 2 days) you can start looking for a negative test that will end isolation.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This depends on the type of ticket. Mainly this will be

1. "Super Sparpreis": you are out of luck
2. "Sparpreis": you can cancel up to one day before departure. You will get a refund minus 10 Euro as a voucher for future travel
3. "Flexpreis": You can get a full cash refund if you cancel up to one day before departure.

As usual, there are tons of other ticket types (groups, Euro, normal, etc), exceptions and side rules. Check your own details.

Bahn doesn't care if you cancel because of Covid or not. They specifically recommend  that you should buy a flex ticket (which is ridiculously expensive) so that you can cancel in case you get Covid.

Answer (score 16):

Unfortunately I don't believe there is anything you can do here, at least not via Deutsche Bahn.

DB's German website has [a Corona-related FAQ page](https://www.bahn.de/info/corona_startseite_bahnde), but there's no mention of any special policy for corona-related cancellations. So it seems that you're left with only the standard options for whichever ticket class you booked - and in this case, that means there is no cancellation/refund available.

If you have travel insurance, you *may* be able to claim some or all of the ticket cost back from your insurance company. However, insurance policies generally have a list of excluded reasons, and in my experience "pandemic" is normally one of them. You would have to check the details of any insurance policy you hold.

Comment: Many carriers (airlines, railways, etc.) had more flexibility even on the cheapest usually non-flexible fares during the peak of the Covid crises, but most have now returned to normal "if it's not flexible, it's not flexible". Not sure what the timeline was in this respect for DB.

Comment: @jcaron At the beginning of the Covid period, DB had extraordinary cancellation policies in case your trip had to be cancelled because of official travel restrictions, in which cases the trains were often cancelled anyway. I don't think they ever had any temporary goodwill-period in which they allowed you to cancel with a refund if the reason for the cancellation was that the customer had Covid.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Did they not? Surprising, many carriers switched to all tickets being refundable (or at least exchangeable) without any justification for quite a while. The reasoning was not so much to accommodate users, but rather to make sure they could still sell tickets at all (people didn't want to commit to non-refundable tickets when you could be prevented from travelling at any minute, and didn't want to/couldn't pay the extra cost for flexible tickets).

Comment: @jcaron No, I can't remember that they ever have. I had a ticket from Germany to Italy just a week after the first Covid restrictions came into effect in spring 2020 and first DB offered me a goodwill-refund of the ticket since I could not travel, but eventually they also cancelled the train, so they would have been required to refund me anyway. Since DB is mostly operating national trains and there have not been too many Covid restrictions related to domestic travel, there have probably not been too many situations where a DB passenger unexpectedly was not able to travel as planned.

Comment: Is self isolation even legally required at this point in Germany? It’s no longer necessary in many other countries.

Comment: @JonathanReez Yes, of course.  And even if it weren't legally required, one should obviously not travel when having an infectious disease.

Comment: Early on in the pandemic, there were relaxed conditions for tickets bought before the pandemic started with travel dates during the pandemic.

Comment: @gerrit if there’s no legal mandate you can still travel if you wear an N95 mask without a valve, that’s perfectly safe for others.

Comment: @JonathanReez this is Germany so the question needs to be asked per relevant Bundesland. But OP mentions travelling from Berlin, so let's look what applies there: [yes, people testing positive are required to isolate](https://www.berlin.de/corona/massnahmen/#headline_1_29)

Comment: @ChrisH ok looks like the self isolation requirement has now been dropped in Bavaria: https://www.muenchen.de/en/stories/current-corona-situation-munich-what-rules-still-apply. But not in Berlin just yet.